# data gets overwritten when using asyncio.gather(func1(),func2())

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I request data from an API.

```
async def get_data(request_details):
    value1, value2 = await api.get_values(request_details)
    ..some extra calculations
    return value1, value2

async def routine1():
    val1, val2 = await get_data(request_details1)
    ...do something with val1, val2

async def routine2():
    val1, val2 = await get_data(request_details2)
    ...do something with val1, val2


async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(routine1(),routine2())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
    loop.close()
```

I need to start both routines so that they can go do their things asynchronously.
What happens, is that I get val1, val2 returned to me by get_data() functions and they are the same.
They are correct for routine1(), but for routine2() they are same as for routine1().

If I change the call for routines in main(): from using asyncio.gather() to

```
await routine1()
await routine2()
```

Then they do not start asynchronously, but I DO GET CORRECT val1,val2 in both.
What am I missing here? Why does my data get sort of overwritten?

Comment: Try inspecting `request_details1` and `request_details2`. Perhaps those mistakenly contain the same object, which would explain getting the same results. Also, try adding prints or debugger breakpoints to see what is going wrong in more detail. As it stands, your question lacks details to be answered.

Comment: request_details1,2 are different objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem with API responses. Asyncio logic performed as supposed to,

Answer (score 0):

as it is it is all correct -chances are the `api.get_values` you are calling is not keeping every async-call independent and they are returning the same value. Apart from you saying which is that API and we looking at its code, there is no way to answer this properly.

Since it is a problem in that API, if it offer a Synchronous call, that might be a workaround - then, in your api call inside `get_data`, instead of awaiting on the broken `api.get_values` you can use `loop.run_in_executor` to call the synchronous version of the api in a separate thread. Hopping the api is thread_safe, that is, then it should work:

```py
async def get_data(request_details):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    value1, value2 = await loop.run_in_executor(api.get_values_sync, request_details)
    ..some extra calculations
    return value1, value2
```